# how to use both hold and click events on the same button in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

```
 void b_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("A", "MessageBox Example", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" ....");

        }



    }

    void b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnevent = (Button)sender;
        for (int i = 0; i < (Application.Current as App).devices.Length; i++)
            if (btnevent.Content.ToString() == (Application.Current as App).devices[i])
            {

                (Application.Current as App).selectedDevice = i;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/pages/Buttons.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
    }
```

I am working on  project and I need to define hold and click events to one button. the problem is  click event always fired even i hold on  or click the button .
in other words ,, can i disable click event when I hold on the buttons  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757052/mouse-clicked-and-released-xna may help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548869/how-to-perform-hold-event-in-windows-phonw-8 or this ^)

Comment: thanks ..  I can handle the hold events , my problem is how to handle click and hold on the same button ?

Comment: The issue is, a hold consists of a click, a wait, and a release. You may have to do something like implement only a click event and write your own method to determine if the button is being held down or tapped. From this, you could decide which behavior to call.

Comment: One thing that is worth trying- Use a Tap event instead of click. That might help with the issue since you won't be relying on legacy mouse code.

Comment: Tap events  worked with me thank you   steveg89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tap instead of click in this style

```
private void Button_OnHold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    // Your code goes here
}

private void Button_OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code goes here
}
```

After you set Handled property to true click event will not handle your gesture.